# display the children of the post using the current page as the main parent

Tags: wp-query, loop, pages

How can I display the childpages of my subpages on the main page using the main page as my first loop? I can display the child pages by inputing the subpages one by one but that is not practically correct.

Main Page

1. SubPages

   - Child 1
   - Child 2
   - Child 3
2. SubPages

   - Child 1
3. SubPages

   - Child 1

**CODE:**

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $query->have_posts()) :
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <article class="index-categories">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </article>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: What is the expected output that you want? Is it "Child 1, Child 2, Child 3, Child 1, Child 1"? I.e. without the "SubPages" in the list.

Comment: yup exactly though i need to output the title of the subpages